# Syntax highlighting of latex code blocks in ikiwiki

Tags: latex, syntax-highlighting, markdown, ikiwiki

Is it possible to get syntax highlighting for LaTeX code blocks in [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info) (just something like it is automatically done in [tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/))?

To avoid misunderstandings: I don't mean math output produced for example by mathjax. I want to document latex-tricks in my wiki, so I have to put some snippets of latex source code in it to show how something is done in latex. For example:

"Here is an example how to use tikz:

```
\begin{document}{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) --node[sloped,above]{$x$} (1,1);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

"

Here the code block above just appears with a grey background but without syntax highlighting of the source code. If I would put the same snipped on tex.sx there would be a syntax highlighting of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For syntaxhighlighting in Ikiwiki there is a plugin called [highlight](http://ikiwiki.info/plugins/highlight/). You can use it like

```
[[!format tex """
\documentclass{scrartcl}
…
"""]]
```

This will give you nice syntax highlighting. It uses Perl bindings. The library itself has a longer [documentation](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want. However I don't see, how to install and enable it. Can you include the relevant steps into your answer? I just did `sudo aptitude install libhighlight-perl` to get the libraries. According to your link then I have to get and install a plugin called format, but I don't know where and how...